# Create 'gltf' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Similar to existing `fbx` and `collada` tags, would others be open to creating a 'gltf' tag? See https://www.khronos.org/gltf/ for format details. It's a relatively new format, but there are currently ~40 questions mentioning glTF, and ~5 in the last month. If those 40 were tagged, it would be a roughly average popularity tag for this site.

Disclaimer — I'm part of the Khronos Group and help to maintain the glTF format. I'd like to use the tag to watch for new posts so I can answer questions and handle any bugs. I don't have 300 reputation, and cannot create tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds good to me, created. Thanks for your time and initiative. Ton has also been a big proponent of the format for a while now and with Eevee, Godot and general support when moving between packages, curating these is a great idea.

Comment: As a type of addendum, please try to keep the answers on-topic as related to Blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/gltf/info. This is an [example of an offtopic question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/64932/12).

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!